# Jquery/AJAX&PHP Domain checker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to build a domain availability checker.

My PHP code is the following:

```
<?php

$domain = $_GET["domname"];

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://freedomainapi.com/?key=XXXXXXX&domain=' . $domain);

echo $returned_content;

?>
```

When called as such: `/domchek.php?domname=google.com`

The JSON output is:

```
{"status":"success","domain":"google.com","available":true}
```

The JQuery im using to call the script is as follows:

```
$.get("domchek.php?domname=google.com", {data: "available"}, function(json) {
    $("html").html(json);
});
```

I just want to return the availability not the entire JSON output. I have tried `json.availability` and a number of other things but can't figure it out. Also if there is a better method for this than `.get()` please suggest it.

**UPDATE:**

```
$.getJSON("domchek.php?domname=google.com", function(json) {
  $("html").html(json.status);
});
```

The above works as does returning json.domain but trying to return json.available - which I require returns nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
$("html").html(json);
```

to:

```
$("html").html(json.status);
```

**UPDATE:** to force the GET request data type to JSON, change to:

```
$.get("domchek.php?domname=google.com", {data: "available"}, function(json) {
    $("html").html(json);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but returns undefined. I think it may be because it is not recognised that I am parsing JSON data.